# mySQLi array directly to json array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, mysqli

Is it possible to get mysqli to spit out an array directly that I then json_encode with php (to retrieve with jquery) ?

I mean.. avoid making a while loop

I have this:

```
    $sql = 'SELECT id, name FROM thetable';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    if ($stmt) {

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            $stmt->bind_result($sql_id, $sql_name);

            $json = array();

            while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                $json[] = $sql_id.'=>'.$sql_name;
            }

            echo json_encode($json);

        }

    }
```

(this is just a simplyfied short version of my code)

Comment: Is that the actual query or just a simplification? Using a prepared statement here without any parameters is overcomplicating it when you could just use `$conn->query('SELECT id, name FROM thetable')->fetch_all()`

Comment: It is simplified here.. But now that your saying it, perhaps I don't need prepared statements just for this. How would the code look then? Just ditch the prepare line?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your query does not have any parameters, you might as well avoid using the prepared statement. Something like this should suffice

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(
    $conn->query('SELECT id, name FROM thetable')
         ->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
);
exit;
```

If you do need the statement, use [`mysqli_stmt::get_result`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
// $stmt->bind_param(...);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
exit;
```

Comment: Gotta try this. Love simplicity.. Is the content header really necessary?

Comment: @mowgli If you're delivering JSON, I'd say so. Otherwise, PHP will use the default header of `text/html` which doesn't match the content

Comment: Ok. Why the exit; afterwards?

Comment: And I do need some checks (like I did in my code), to see if the query returns something. So I guess I have to split that compact echo line

Comment: @mowgli The `exit` is to make sure there's no other data coming after the JSON. You could put checks in but an empty array is just as good IMHO

Comment: Well yes.. it is.. Thinking. But the thing is, I use the same file for both php (include) and jquery (ajax). And for the php file that includes this, it has to have some checking of db result rows. How can I use your first bit of code, and just one check if there was more than one row returned?

Comment: `echo ...` can be replaced with `exit(json_encode($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)));` since `exit()` will output the string that it is given.

Comment: @mickmackusa less lines of code is best lines of code. Be interested to see if the byte code differs at all